# How to parse MP3 data to extract numbered frames?

Tags: linux, parsing, mp3, frame

I am writing a streaming application for MP3 (CBR).  It is all passthru, meaning I don't have to decode/encode, I just need to pass on the data as I see it come through.  I want to be able to count the MP3 frames as they passthru (and some other stuff like throughput calculations).

According to the [MP3 frame header](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) spec, the sync word appears to be eleven (11) bits of 1s, *however* I notice (naturally) that the frame payload which I should safely assume to be binary and thus it is not odd at all to see eleven (11) 1s in sequence.

My questions:

1. Is there a Unix|Linux|Perl MP3 parser utility (`dd`-style) that can pull numbered frames from an MP3 file/pipe?
2. How does one delineate an MP3 header block from any other binary payload data? and lastly:
3. Is a constant bitrate (CBR) MP3 defined by payload bytes or are the header bytes included in the aggregate # of bytes/bits per any given timeslice?

Thanks,

Comment: dd-style? You mean something that is confusing to use, works in awkward units rather than bytes, and when using byte chunks *after all*, becomes naturally slow... (I think you want `dd_rescue` in the future for copying data.)

Comment: Well, dd style meaning that I could either name/number a frame for extraction to a pipe &| file or that I could specify frame ranges in the way that dd does skip|seek|count.  dd has it's own issues no doubt, but does dd_rescue support seek?

Comment: @Brad, I'll use any language (well, that I can run on Unix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab at #2.

It is my understanding that the common way to sync to the MP3 stream (and thus allow for your counting of the frames) is to do this:

- Search for a sync word
- When sync word is found, validate the rest of the header
- If the frame header is valid, then you should know the position of the next header
- If you hit 3 or 4 headers in a row, and they are valid, then chances are very high that you have  found them.

I saw a page recently with documentation on this, but I can't find it at the moment.  If I find it again, I will post it.

Comment: There was a talk about this just a while ago concerning Erlang's bit-wise regexps, but it is non-trivial to bitwise match into the MP3 frame header patterns.  Any reference would be great :)

Comment: I decided to not boil the ocean and keep all files strict-CBR and stick with `dd`.  `bs=$[144*$bitrate/$samplerate]` seems to work charms.